# How can I use list view to display some item in a news app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making a news app and using list view to display item in app . how can I make image in my activity_main.xml file scrollable? This is my activity_main.xml code.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- Layout for a list of earthquakes -->
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/qtc" />
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_image"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/home_image"
            android:dividerHeight="4dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_indicator"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Put it in the list view header, and it will scroll with the list view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **parallax animation** that sticks to the top of a list when scrolled.

https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-listview-parallax-effect-with-a-sticky